# Python: getting lowest integer in list of tuples

Tags: python, list, integer, tuples, min

My current plan is to determine which is the first entry in a number of [Tkinter](http://wiki.python.org/moin/TkInter) listboxes highlighted using `.curselection()` and combining all of the resulting tuples into a list, producing this:

```
tupleList = [(), (), ('24', '25', '26', '27'), (), (), (), ()]
```

I'm wondering as to how to determine the lowest integer. Using `.min(tupleList)` returns only `()`, being the lowest entry in the list, but I'm looking for a method that would return 24.

What's the right way to get the lowest integer in any tuple in the list?

Comment: Instead of appending items to the list, use `.extend` method. You'll have a list of integers and then use `min()` to easily find the minimum.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
>>> nums = [(), (), ('24', '25', '26', '27'), (), (), (), ()]
>>> min(int(j) for i in nums for j in i)
24
```

Comment: Thank you rubik and jamylak, both solutions are brilliant.
Great thanks to gnibbler, a perfect solution for this situation without having to edit a thing.

Comment: @jamylak, Your solution would make sense if `nums` was being returned from a generator. Especially if it were dealing with a large amount of data

Answer (score 6):

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> nums = [(), (), ('24', '25', '26', '27'), (), (), (), ()]
>>> min(map(int,chain.from_iterable(nums)))
24
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> min(reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, nums))
```

Comment: Doesn't work if nums has a number like `'100'` because it is checked alphabetically since it is still a `str`. Test it on `nums = [(), (), ('24', '25', '26', '27'), (), (), (), (),('100',)]` for example. Also be careful about using `reduce` because it is not liked in Python since there is usually a better option for almost every task.

Comment: Actually '100' is less than '24', I don't understand your point.

Comment: I'm pretty sure he wants to check the strings as numbers since he wants to find the minimum. He mentioned in the post: `'determine the lowest integer'`

Comment: @jamylak There are no integers in the structure, however your comments make sense.